# Can't we use [specifier] with like operator with Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

When using the LIKE operator in oracle for matching anyone of the characters can't I use [*specifier*]
For eg. Find out the Customer's name starting with either 's' or 'r' SO we can't write query as
" select * from emp where customer LIKE '[sr]%'";

Can't we use "[]" braces with LIKE operator in ORACLE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, LIKE does not do that.

But you can use regular expressions.

```
select * from emp where REGEXP_LIKE (customer, '^[sr].*');
```

Comment: Ok thanx its working... But '^' in the above regular expression means are we excluding it or are we including it..??

Comment: Can you give me a good link from where I can study in detail about regexp_like in oracle..?? Thanx

Comment: Oracle dot com http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1003